# How to open Storage Container in Azure Storage Explorer w/ only Storage Blob Data Contributor Role?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, roles, azure-storage-account

I granted someone in my org a `Storage Blob Data Contributor` Role on an Azure Storage Account. The user is unable to add the Storage Account to Azure Storage Explorer (ASE).

Upon opening ASE (and being authenticated to the correct Azure Subscription), the Storage Account is not listed under `Emulated & Attached`.

**Steps taken by user to attempt to connect:**

1. Open ASE
2. Click `Open Connect Dialog`
3. Select `ADLS Gen2 Container or Directory`

   - Note: `Account kind` = `StorageV2 (general purpose v2)` which *I think* is considered ADLS Gen2
4. Select `Sign-in with AAD`, then Sign-in as needed
5. Name the connection and enter the Container URL

**Issue:**

For the user in question, at this point of the process, the `Next` button is grayed out.

(Its available to me in the screenshot as I have correct role).

[image]

As soon as I give the user `Contribute` access on the Account, they refresh and the Account shows up under the `Emulated & Attached` section of ASE. However, `Contribute` Role on the entire Account is too permissive in this case and was done only for troubleshooting.

**Question**:

- How do users with `Storage Blob Data Contributor` Role interact with Storage Containers in ASE?

Answer (score 1):

Note that, `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role is **enough** to interact with storage containers in ASE.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one general purpose v2 storage account and assigned **"Storage Blob Data Contributor"** role to one user like below:

[image]

Now I signed into Azure Storage Explorer with **demo user** account like below:

[image]

I followed **same steps** as you mentioned to connect storage container like below:

[image]

To connect, I selected **Sign in using Azure AD account** like below:

[image]

Make sure to select correct user and **tenant** like below:

[image]

When I entered connection name and container URL, the `Next` button is **not** grayed out for me like below:

[image]

After selecting `Next`, I got **Summary** screen to connect as below:

[image]

Now, I'm able to see the connection successfully under **`Emulated & Attached`** like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Azure Storage Explorer troubleshooting guide | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-troubleshooting?tabs=Windows)

Comment: Thank you for reproducing the issue. I just reproduced with the again, just to be sure, and the issue lies with the 6th screenshot you have above. The user is unable to get the "Next" button to be active. When they add a Connection Name and below that, the URL, the Next button is not available to click.

Comment: I also had a separate but related issue today with a separate user. User had `Storage Blob Data Contributor` access to an Azure Storage Account. User could connect to the Storage Account using the above process. But none of the data was visible in the Container! I added a Role for `Contributor`, had them refresh, then the data appeared. I removed the `Contributor` Role, leaving their original `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role and the data **remained visible** after many refreshes *and* closing/reopening Azure Storage Explorer!

Comment: How do I determine if the issue is with the Role itself, the VPN, caching or Azure Storage Explorer itself?

Comment: Could you include the **version** of Azure Storage Explorer that you currently using?

Comment: All of us are on v1.27.1.